# How to put the output of the trailing lines of grep in on-line?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Assuming that I have this file:

```
 Thu May  8 15:32:07 2014
        User-Name = "Mark"
        Framed-IP-Address = 0.0.0.0
        Acct-Status-Type = Interim-Update
        Acct-Input-Octets = 95684
        Acct-Output-Octets = 23564

    Thu May  8 15:32:07 2014
        User-Name = "Mike"
        Framed-IP-Address = 0.0.0.0
        Acct-Status-Type = Interim-Update
        Acct-Input-Octets = 95684
        Acct-Output-Octets = 23564
    Thu May  8 15:32:07 2014
        User-Name = "Mike"
        Framed-IP-Address = 0.0.0.0
        Acct-Status-Type = Interim-Update
        Acct-Input-Octets = 95684
        Acct-Output-Octets = 23564

    Thu May  8 15:32:07 2014
        User-Name = "Mark"
        Framed-IP-Address = 0.0.0.0
        Acct-Status-Type = Interim-Update
        Acct-Input-Octets = 95684
        Acct-Output-Octets = 23564
```

I have managed to get the Information that are related to a user using `grep` with `-A` option:

```
grep -A4 "Mark" test
        User-Name = "Mark"
        Framed-IP-Address = 0.0.0.0
        Acct-Status-Type = Interim-Update
        Acct-Input-Octets = 95684
        Acct-Output-Octets = 23564
--
        User-Name = "Mark"
        Framed-IP-Address = 0.0.0.0
        Acct-Status-Type = Interim-Update
        Acct-Input-Octets = 95684
        Acct-Output-Octets = 23564
```

but my desired output is something like that:

```
User-Name = "Mark" 
            Acct-Input-Octets = 95684 95684
            Acct-Output-Octets = 23564 23564
```

as we notice I want to eliminate the first two lines after "Mark" `Framed-IP-Address = 0.0.0.0`, `Acct-Status-Type = Interim-Update` and put all the values of the same field in the same line?

as [Warwick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/72876/warwick) suggest,the first part of my question can be easily answered:

```
grep -A4 "Mark" test| grep -v Framed-IP-Address | grep -v Acct-Status-Type
```

Note this is an example, the file may contain a lot of section with User-Name ="Mark" and the desired output will be something like that:

```
User-Name = "Mark" 
                Acct-Input-Octets = val1 val2 val3 val4 .......
                Acct-Output-Octets = val1 val2 val3 val4 ........
```

Comment: The first part of your question would be fairly easily achieved by adding to your command `| grep -v Framed-IP-Address | grep -v Acct-Status-Type`. For the second part of your question, if you are familiar with Perl, then I'd suggest using objects or hashes of arrays, where the array elements are the values.

Comment: Are you open to other solutions? **grep** isn't smart enough for this.

Comment: any command will work for me @CristianCiupitu

Comment: Are the blank lines between datasets optional?

Comment: @tink, no it is always exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`search.awk`

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "="
    cur_username = ""
}

$1 ~ /User-Name/ {
    cur_username = $2
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", cur_username)
    gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", cur_username)
}

$1 !~ /User-Name/ {
    if ((NF != 2) || (cur_username != searched_user))
        next

    key = $1
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", key)
    gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", key)

    value = $2
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", value)
        gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", value)

    values[key] = values[key] " " value
}

END {
    printf("User-Name = %s\n", searched_user)
    for(key in values) {
        printf("\t%s =%s\n", key, values[key])
    }
}
```

Test run:

```
$ awk -f search.awk -v 'searched_user="Mark"' input 
User-Name = "Mark"
    Acct-Status-Type = Interim-Update Interim-Update
    Acct-Input-Octets = 95684 95684
    Framed-IP-Address = 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
    Acct-Output-Octets = 23564 23564
```

---

Bonus - `group.awk` for grouping all the records (too bad **nawk** doesn't have [`asorti`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)):

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "="
    cur_username = ""
}

$1 ~ /User-Name/ {
    cur_username = $2
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", cur_username)
    gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", cur_username)
}

$1 !~ /User-Name/ {
    if (NF != 2)
        next

    key = $1
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", key)
    gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", key)

    value = $2
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", value)
        gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", value)

    users[cur_username,key] = users[cur_username,key] " " value
}

END {
    n = asorti(users, sorted)
    prev_username = ""
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        username_key = sorted[i]
        split(username_key, a, SUBSEP)
        username = a[1]
        key = a[2]
        value = users[sorted[i]]
        if (username != prev_username) {
            printf("User-Name = %s\n", username)
            prev_username = username
        }
        printf("\t%s =%s\n", key, value)
    }
}
```

Test run:

```
$ gawk -f group.awk input 
User-Name = "Mark"
    Acct-Input-Octets = 95684 95684
    ...
User-Name = "Mike"
    Acct-Input-Octets = 95684 95684
    ...
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply but this is didn't work its output is something like that:`User-Name = "Mark"`, for Info I'm using centos6.5

Comment: You're right, the same is happening to me with gawk-3.1.7-10.el6.i686, although it worked fine with gawk-4.1.0-3.fc20.x86_64.

Comment: @Networker, it looks like that old gawk doesn't know about the `\s` regex.

Comment: so I have to upgrade `gawk`

Comment: No, I've updated the answer in case you haven't noticed. It should work with **gawk** 3 too or even other Awk implementations, e.g. **nawk**.

Comment: @Thanks I tested the updated answer and it worked like charm

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
awk -vRS= -F'\n' '$2 ~ /Mark/ {
  vals["User-Name"] = "Mark"
  for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) {
    split($i,a," = ");
    vals[a[1]]=sprintf("%s %s", vals[a[1]], a[2]);
  }
}     
END{for (i in vals) print i,"=",vals[i];}' test
```

which for your `test` file gives

```
User-Name = Mark
        Acct-Input-Octets =  95684 95684
        Acct-Output-Octets =  23564 23564
```

Comment: The `sprintf` based concatenation could be replaced with `vals[a[1]]=vals[a[1]] " " a[2]`.

Comment: @Steeldriver,Thanks for your reply but this will work only if we have user "mark"two times, as I said before the file may contain a lot of section with User-Name ="Mark".

Comment: It should work for any number of instances, provided the data blocks are separated by blank lines. I reduplicated your test input and confirmed it worked with 4 instances.

Answer (score 2):

1. Filter the desired paragraphs, to collect the data about this one user.
2. Filter lines containing the desired keys (`Acct-Input-Octets` and `Acct-Output-Octets`). You may want to normalize spacing at this stage if it isn't consistent.
3. Sort entries by key (using a stable sort unless you don't care about the order of the values).
4. Collapse sequences of identical keys.

```
awk -v RS= '/User-Name = "Mark"/' |
grep -E 'Acct-(Input|Output)-Octets *=' |
sort -k1,1 -s |
awk '
  BEGIN {printf "User-Name = \"Mark\""}
  $1 == key { printf " %s", $3; }
  $1 != key { key = $1; printf "\n%s", $0; }
  END { print "" }'
```